# Replacing a csv field value using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file like the following example:

```
fieldname1: "This is field1", "id":55, fieldname2: "This is field2", "id":66
```

I would like to replace the fourth field from ""id":66" to ""id":72" using the awk command. I have tried it the following way but am getting a syntax error:

```
awk -F, '{${4}="\"id\":999";}1' OFS=, rule.txt
```

The error is:

> awk: {${4}="\"id\":999";}1
>
> awk:   ^ syntax error
>
> awk: {${4}="\"id\":999";}1
>
> awk:       ^ syntax error
>
> awk: cmd. line:1: {${4}="\"id\":999";}1
>   awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Any suggestions for correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to say `$4` instead of `${4}`:

```
$ awk -F, '{$4="\"id\":999";}1' OFS=, file
#           ^^
fieldname1: "This is field1", "id":55, fieldname2: "This is field2","id":999
```

If you want to give the value via a variable, use `-v value="$bash_var"` as usual:

```
$ awk -F, -v val=999 '{$4="\"id\":" val;}1' OFS=, file
#         ^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^
fieldname1: "This is field1", "id":55, fieldname2: "This is field2","id":999
```

Note that `${ }` is used in Bash to avoid confusion when using a variable `$hello` being confused with `$hello_you` when saying eg `echo "$hello_you"` -> in that case, you would say `echo "${hello}_you"` to define the scope of the name of the variable.

But in `awk` such thing shouldn't be necessary because you enclose the string part in double quotes:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {a=23; print a"_b"}'
23_b
```

Comment: Thanks that works! How about if I would like to replace '999' with a bash variable, would that be possible?